# how to call trigger function in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

how to call a separate trigger function in oracle . I understand that in postgres the syntax for calling a trigger function is

```
create OR replace trigger_test 
after update or delete on person_info 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION trig_function();
```

Also in postgres i can get all the old and new values of the table person_info in the function trig_function().

Is there a way to simulate the same thing in oracle as i found the documentation regarding trigger a bit contrast with postgres triggers.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "trigger function" in Oracle (and that code doesn't "call" that function to begin with). The complete syntax to create a trigger is documented [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle triggers are a monolithic entry consisting of the header (`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER...`) and a PL/SQL block which is invoked when the triggering event occurs. An example is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEES_BIU
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEES
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE                    -- This is only included to demonstrate that 
  nSome_variable  NUMBER;  -- you can include a DECLARE section.
BEGIN                      
  IF INSERTING THEN
    :NEW.ADD_DATE := SYSDATE;
    :NEW.ADD_USER := UID;
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    :NEW.ADD_DATE := :OLD.ADD_DATE;
    :NEW.ADD_USER := :OLD.ADD_USER;
    :NEW.MTC_DATE := SYSDATE;
    :NEW.MTC_USER := UID;
  END IF;
END EMPLOYEES_BIU;
```

Old and new values are available through the pseudo-rows `:OLD` and `:NEW`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to call a function from within a trigger. If that is the case then you can do something like

```
create or replace trigger trigger_test
after update or delete on person_info 
for each row
declare
c_person person_info<specify your type>%TYPE
begin
if trig_function(:NEW.person) != c_person; -- not sure what your function returns
--your logic here

end if;
end; 
/
```

or you can do something like

```
create or replace trigger trigger_test
    after update or delete on person_info 
    for each row
    begin
   if trig_function(:NEW.person) != "ABC"  ---- not sure what your function returns
   ----implement your logic with the function

   end if;
    end; 
    /
```

Comment: what is the reason for trig_function(:NEW.person) != "ABC" .  why can't i directly call the trigger function

Comment: @Abhishek As I don't know what your function would be returning. I just assumed in the provided example it would return a string/varchar so did that. I have edited my answer

Comment: You cannot directly call the trigger function because there is **_no such thing in Oracle_** corresponding to a Postgres trigger function. The trigger itself contains the code, see answer by @BobJarvis. The reason for the function is an example that the trigger can call a function. Perhaps, the function name chosen is misleading as the trigger can call any function (subject to appropriate access).

Comment: @Paul Can't I pass old and new datastructure to the trig_function() procedure

Comment: @Abhishek how are you trying to pass the values? the main purpose of a trigger in databases, you can't raise it explicitly, if you want it to run the only way is to raise the event. Also passing parameters isn't part of trigger definition, but you can handle the event attributes,(which can be passed to the trigger body that may can contain functions or procedures). What I can suggest that you write your own select statement to get the values in the body of the trigger and call your function and implement your logic.